# Subcategories Are Not Being Made Up in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

I have a tiny problem, if anybody could help me please. I have serached for solution but without any gain. I am trying to make categories and subcategories in OC 3.0.2.0 with default theme. I have made category "Stationery" in the main menue bar. Then I tried to make its subcategory "Pens" in the left side bar. This subcategory "Pens" is appearing in the left side bar. Then I attempted to make two subcategories "Fountain Pens" and "Ballpoint Pens" of subcategory "Pens".

My category and subcategory detail is:

```
Stationery (Main Category)
Stationery > Pens (Subcategory)
Stationery > Pens > Fountain Pens (Subcategory)
Stationery > Pens > Ballpoint Pens (Subcategory)
```

When I hover over "Stationery" in the main menue bar, then under drop down only appears "Pens(0)" and "Show All Stationery". When I click Show All Stationery, then a page is displayed with following information

```
Stationery
Refine Search
Pens(0)
```

Here when I click on Pens(0), then a page is displayed with following details

```
Pens
Refine Search
Fountain Pens(0)
Ballpoint Pens(0)
```

We can see that subcategories are do appearing but not at correct place.

I have no idea how to solve this problem. I would be greately thankful, if anybody offers me the solution.

My admin side category listing is:

[My category detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d7Th.png)

Comment: send me your website URL ?

Comment: Website URL is gulrung.pk

Comment: dear @Arslan Khan i will find issue. and response to as soon as possible.

Comment: send me admin side category listing full screenshot.

Comment: if I correctly understand main question, you should just try type sub category name in category field and it appear in popup, then just click on subcategory what you need.

Comment: Thanks brother @K.B. for your time. Actually it is not the problem that subcategories do not appear in the dropdown in admin side. If we write sub category name in the category field, it appears in the dropdown. My problem is that I am not being able to create third level subcategories of a category. For example Stationery > Pens > Fountain Pens. In the front side of site, Fountain Pens should appear under Pens. But it is not appearing in left side bar of front side of the site. My website URL is gulrung.pk

Comment: Have you tried this plugin? https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=30089&filter_search=third%20level%20category&filter_license=0&filter_download_id=45 or  another from the list: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension&filter_search=third%20level%20category&filter_download_id=45&filter_license=0

Comment: Dear @K.B. thanks for your effort. Actually I do not want to use extensions. I want the solution within the OC. Is it not there anyone? Or I would have to use the plugin. Actually with plugins,if we solve one problem then another problem may rise. Can we not make third level subcategories within OC 3.0.2.0? If I make Stationery > Pencils or Stationery > Highlighters, then they appear in the left side bar. But Stationery > Pens > Fountain Pens is not appearing

Answer (score 0):

You can allocated category on particular product; your category is perfect right now.

But you can going to admin -> catalog -> products and edit any one product.

Open Links tab: see screen shot as well, for better understanding.

[image: SEE SCREENSHOT]

After you can allocate category

For example, **Stationery > Pens**.

Comment: Dear @Mujahid Bhoraniya, Sorry your suggested solution is not working for me. I have appended category listing image above. Please have a look on it. I have assigned a product to category Sationery > Pens > Fountain Pens but with no effect. Thanks